# Linux file permission issue for AD Domain users

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-mint, network-shares, active-directory

I have a Linux mint box used as DB server Domain users are access the shared folder from Linux mint but Linux machine is not joined to AD we are having file folder permission issue i have tried changing permissions for users and group=766 on the folder DB-3 but it only changes it for existing files, every time new file is created it goes back to 644 which leaves AD users unable to execute the .db files on their machines so i have to run chmod 766 few times a day, it looks like folders permissions are not inheriting to newly created files can someone please help me how to make those changes permanent so new file in DB-310 folder will take show up with 766 permission thanks.

Comment: To be clear.  While Linux can trust an AD Domain user, you will still use Linux permissions, it sounds like you should configure what the default permission should be.  I suggest using the User group on the domain as the group ownership, and an Administrator account on the AD Domain, as the owner.

Comment: hmm sounds like a plan I will give it a try, my question is in db-3 folder files being created with 644 permission and owner is manager so if I changed that permission to 766 wouldn't it do it though .

Comment: You need to define what the default permission is.  That way all new files are created with that permission.  You can also define which user and user group are used by default.  You obviously should also define what permissions everyone should have. Setting the permission on the folder, only applies to future files, provided the default isn't set to be something else.

Comment: Yes I know that I have to define permission but how I don't know I need to know how can I apply 755 permission on new files chmod -Rm 755 is good for existing files in DB-3 folder it doesn't gets applied on new files